# How can I reattach her hand?

Tags: snapping

[image]I created a new hand for my character but I can't seem to reattach it perfectly. I've tried snapping the vertices of the hand with the character and it won't snap. Is there a way to attach the arm so it doesn't seem jagged?[image]

Comment: are they in the same object as the rest of the body? Also if you want to snap vertices you need to enable the snap to vertex option, and you can also enable the auto merge option

Comment: They are different objects. She didn't have a hand, so I created one for her. I am going experiment with your recommendations. Thank you moonboots.

Comment: unless you have some reason to keep them separate objects, you'd better join the hands with the body (select the hands, shift select the body, and Ctrl J)

Comment: I have tried the Ctrl J option, but it does not attach perfectly. When I use Ctrl J, it looks more like a glove vs. a real hand. I would like her wrist to not look "attached."

Comment: Ctrl J is just to join the two objects if they are separate  ;)

Comment: I appreciate it. :)